# How to echo a ' . ' in every 3 seconds while your application is running?

Tags: php

I am running my PHP in CLI.
My script might take about 3-4 mn to complete.
When looking at the CLI, all I see is this :

[image]

That doesn't help me much, I am not sure whether my application is stuck or still running. (Visually)

What is the best way to keep track of that ? 
I am thinking to echo "." in every 3 seconds while my application is running.

Basically, I want to give myself some visually feedback while my script is loading/running.

**If you going to suggest me to log it :**
I actually do log my $response and output it to a file somewhere in my desktop, and the reason why I am asking this question, I just want to create a visually feedback - like when you playing a video game and while you waiting for something to finish loading, you will see the screen with `Now loading ........` or something that is similar to that - am I right ?

Yes - I want to make something similar to that !

Comment: Do you not know how much progress it has gone through or what it's doing? If you know what it's doing, then print what it's doing. Progress only makes it better. It also depends on what your application does. Is it slow because it runs a super slow SQL query (blocking PHP) or slow because it runs a big loop (not blocking PHP)?

Comment: It's making a cURL request and posting about 30,000 object in 1 jSON, compare it with other JSON that I grab from other API, and insert on the `match` one in to my database, and return back the response at the end !

Comment: @kula I updated my answer based on this comment.  You can add a check in your loop to make this pretty easy.

Comment: I saw that - thanks. I will make sure to accept it - when it's work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than echo out the " . " every 3 seconds I can just do echo "." after every-line of code.

Now - I got this result - close enough to what I want anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just let your program write a log file whilst it's running. Like this, you can log every single move, every detail you are interested in. And watch the progress in the file and let the program do what it should do.

A great tool for this is [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) which makes it very easy to log in case of errors or success.

As I just read your comment, once again, let it log the moves...

Comment: I will try monolog thank-you. I actually do log my $response and output it to a file somewhere in my desktop, and the reason why I am asking this question, I just want to create a visually feedback - like when you playing a video game and while you waiting for something to finish loading, you will see the screen with ` Now loading ........ ` or something that is similar to that - am I right ?

Comment: I like the video game comparison... :) Better watch the now loading in your file. :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is synchronous by nature, it won't move on to the next line until the previous command has returned.

You can use it asynchronously by using threading (pthreads)  or running commands in a background shell.

**Update:**
Since you stated in the comments: "posting about 30,000 object in 1 jSON".  I'm assuming these are in a loop?  Why not do something like this?

```
$time = time();
for {
    # post object here
    if (time()-$time >= 3) {
        echo '.';
        $time = time();
    }
}
```

Pretty simple solution.  Won't output exactly every 3 seconds, but it should be good enough for your purpose (just making sure things are progressing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do like control points... You could `echo` everytime you finalize a task... If you are doing loops you can `echo` every new loop if the loop is not too big.

That way you know in what point of the task you are. I think you get the idea, also you should check your vars for the expected types. That way no function should have any error.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use [register_tick_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) to have a callback executed during execution - just record how long its been since you last output anything, and send more output when that's expire.

Really though, it's better to design an application to provide feedback or logging from the outset. But it's good to know register_tick_function is available!

Comment: Thank you for sparing your knowledge - good to know that it's out there for us.